# Python - how can I iterate through JSON data with json.load

Tags: python, json

I have the below JSON, which I parse with json.load()

```
{
"participants": [
    {
        "name": "Joseph Bloggs"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Doe"
    }
],
"messages": [
    {
        "sender_name": "Joseph Bloggs",
        "timestamp_ms": 1606943360034,
        "content": "Hello John",
        "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
        "sender_name": "John Doe",
        "timestamp_ms": 1606943285176,
        "content": "Hi Joe",
        "type": "Generic"
    },
```

I tried to iterate through the messages to search for strings inside each value.

```
import json 

data = json.load(f)
   
for msg in data['messages']:

    search = 'Jo'

    if search in str(msg['sender_name']) :
      print (msg['sender_name'])
```

This works and outputs a "Joe Bloggs" or "John Doe" string for every message object.

If I try and search for *any other keys*, timestamp, content, type, I get a KeyError, e.g. trying to search for all messages where they participants use the word "Hello".

```
if search in str(msg['content']) :
          print (msg['content'])
```

results in a key error:

```
in <module>
    if search in str(msg['content']) :
KeyError: 'content'
```

I think I am not understanding something about json.load and Python dictionaries/lists. Why is it that msg[sender_name] works but not msg[content]? Thanks

Comment: Do all the messages have a `content` ?

Comment: Please include a working JSON file and runnable code that produces the error that you encountered. It's hard to help you as is, since there are so many things that could go wrong.

Comment: @DaniMesejo No, not all messages have a content now I think about it...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried .get('content') and it worked...

```
 search = 'Thing I am searching for'

    if search in str(msg.get('content')) :
        print (msg.get('content'))
```

If anyone could elaborate I would appreciate it. I've found a solution, but I'd like to understand the 'why'.
Thanks

Comment: .get() Handles the scenarios when you have no `content` as key in your dictionary, you could pass a default as well to it if you wanted to, which comes handy in case of nested dicts

Comment: also you might want to be careful about the str() method, for example if you search string in "one" then for all the none matching value you will get "None" -s as `str(msg.get('content'))` will be `"None"` so you might want to default it to nothing instead - `msg.get('content', "")`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid KeyError with the .get() method on the dictionary

```
if search in str(msg.get('content')):
    print(str(msg.get('sender_name')))
```